# From where to do Google play console ID verification?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-console

I have recently opened my google play developer account. I have uploaded one app but still I am not getting any link from where I can verify my identity. I know that to upload app in google play we need to verify the identity. What goes wrong here ?

Comment: When you try to release an application (Internal Release or Production release) from your Google Play Console, it will show you an error saying you need to complete your Google Play ID Verification, also you'll find a link from there to move forward with the verification. Once click on that link, you'll be asked to input your personal information like address etc and from there on you can find instructions how to move further with the verification.

Comment: I have started a full rollout already. I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [here](https://support.readyeducation.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046966754-Google-Play-Developer-Account-Creation)

After registering for the Google Play Account, you may be asked to [Verify your ID](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9198012) with Google in order to publish apps to the Play Store.

For verifying your identity:

> You need to upload a person’s ID (Driver's license, Passport, etc.)
> from the Google Play Console- that person can be anybody working at
> your institution
>
> Having an unverified ID for your Google Play Developer account means
> the app can’t be published
>
> Having an unverified ID for your Google Play Developer account means
> the app transfer can't be complete

For more information on submitting the document, please visit [Verify your Identity](https://support.google.com/pay/india/answer/9115406?hl=en&visit_id=637658366069925214-503929037&rd=1) on the dedicated Google support page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I have messaged customer service and they have said that no need to do ID verification for my account. I don't why.... But my problem finished finally

Comment: Great.. Consider accept the answer if it is useful..